# What does Document() do?

Tags: javascript, function

I was messing around with Chrome's console, and I found a function (in all websites) named `Document`.  I tried to look this up, but since Google isn't case sensitive, I just found info about `document.getElement...()`.  This function doesn't appear to be a JSON object, like `document`, but an actual function.

[image]

What is this function, and what is it used for?

The [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) still seems to be referencing `document` instead of `Document`, as seen below.

[image]

I just tested this in Firefox with both the built in console and Firebug, and it returns the same as the above screenshot.

I have found that both MDN and W3 reference the `document` object as "Document", even though the `Document` function is not the same as the `document` object.

Comment: [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) — search “document mdn”.

Answer (score 1):

The `Document` interface represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an entry point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree. The DOM tree includes elements such as `<body>` and `<table>`, among many others. It provides functionality which is global to the document, such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

Comment: this still seems to be dealing with `document` (lowercase), as I see whenever I follow any link on that mdn page.  I will include a screenshot and some more information as an edit to my question.

Comment: `document` is likely an instance of `Document`

Comment: You can create more instances of `Document` with e.g. jQuery's `parseXML()` function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/